# Finding minimal polynomial of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Let T: V $\rightarrow$ V be a linear operator with the minimal polynomial $m(x)=(x-1)x^8$,

find the minimal polynomial of $T^3$.

I know that 0 and 1 eigenvalues of $T$ and $T^3$, but I don't know how to continue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $(T^3-1)(T^3)^3=0$ and $(T^3-1)(T^3)^2 \neq 0$ and $(T^3)^3 \neq 0$, hence the minimal polynomial of $T^3$ is $(x-1)x^3$.

Comment: Why $(T^3-1)(T^3)^2 \neq 0$ and $(T^3)^3 \neq 0$?

Comment: Write those expressions as polynomials in $T$ and note that they are not divisible by the mininal polynomial.