# Let $ \phi : L \to L $ be a linear operator with minimal polynomial $ m_\phi (x) = (x-1)x^8 $. What is the minimal polynomial of $ \phi^3 $?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

**Problem**: Let $ \phi : L \to L $ be a linear operator with minimal polynomial $ m_\phi (x) = (x-1)x^8 $. What is the minimal polynomial of $ \phi^3 $?

**Attempt**: from the minimal polynomial I deduced that the eigenvalues are $ \lambda_{1,2} = 1,0 $. I know these eigenvalues will also be the only eigenvalues of $ \phi^3 $ hence the minimal polynomial for $ \phi^3 $ will be $ m_{\phi^3} (x) = (x-1)^{r_1} x^{r_2} $ where $ r_1,r_2 $ are the multiplicities I have to find.

I don't know how to continue, I thought of two options:
One which is to use the Primary Decomposition theorem to get 2 transformations with the minimal polynomials $ x^8 $ and $ (x-1) $, solve for each one of them and then combine the answers.
Second is to use the jordan form of the transformation - we know the size of the largest jordan block that corresponds to each eigenvalue, so I'd write the jordan form, raise it to the third power and see what happens. But the problem is that I don't know what $ dim V $ is to be able to deduce further details about the jordan form

**Note**: I've found the following question which asks exactly the same thing [Finding minimal polynomial of an operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673174/finding-minimal-polynomial-of-an-operator)
but I don't fully understand why $ (T^3-1)(T^3)^2 \neq 0 $ , $ (T^3)^3 \neq 0 $.
If I couldn't deduce these last two equalities, how could've I proceeded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea about the Primary Decomposition Theorem is a good one.

So $L=M\oplus N$, where $M,N$ are $\phi$-invariant, and the minimal polynomial of $\phi$ on $M$ is $x-1$, and on $N$ is $x^8$.

Hence $\phi^3$ acts as the identity on $M$ as well, with minimal polynomial $x-1$.

On $N$ note that $(\phi^3)^2=\phi^6\ne 0$ but that $(\phi^3)^3=\phi^9=0$; so that the minimal polynomial of $\phi^3$ is $x^3$.

Hence the minimal polynomial of $\phi^3$ on $L$  is $x^3(x-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$T^9 = 0$ would imply that zero is the only eigenvalue of $T$. In contradiction with its known minimal polynomial and the fact that $1$ is an eigenvalue.

And you can't either have $(T^3-1)T^6 = 0$ as the minimal polynomial doesn't divide this polynomial.

*Remember that the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides any polynomial that vanishes $T$.*